# why firebase gets undefined while login through cypress-firebase npm module?

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I'm using

```json
"cypress-firebase": "^2.0.0",
"firebase-admin": "^9.11.1"
```

In my cypress `command.js` file:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { attachCustomCommands } from "cypress-firebase";

const fbConfig = {
}

firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

attachCustomCommands({ Cypress, cy, firebase });
```

When I try to execute the code, I face the following issue:

> **TypeError**
>
> The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress:
>
> > Cannot read property 'initializeApp' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

In v9 of the Firebase SDK the API surface changed to using modular, tree-shakeable code. Expect pretty much every piece of documentation or example code you see to have been written for v8 or older Firebase SDK versions that need updating.

Read more [about migrating here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Because `cypress-firebase` has not yet been updated to support the v9 SDK, you need to import the compatibility SDK instead. Note that the compatibility SDK is deprecated and ideally you should find a package that has been updated to support v9.

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/database";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";
import { attachCustomCommands } from "cypress-firebase";

const fbConfig = {
}

firebase.initializeApp(fbConfig);

attachCustomCommands({ Cypress, cy, firebase });
```